# Модифицировать метод

Tags: javascript, функции, методы

У меня есть

```
var Actions = {
    damage : function(count,type){
        return function(){
            var _damage = {
                type : type ,
                count : count
            };
        G.enemy.take_damage[(_damage.type || this.damage)].call(G.enemy, (_damage.count || this.count));
//берутся внутренние хар-ки или самой карты, если внутренних нет
        }
    },
}
```

Объект создающий функции. 
Далее они вызываются вот так :

```
var attack = Actions.damage(1);
//this == card
attack.call(this);
```

Теперь к моей проблеме, я хочу сделать функцию, которая будет модифицировать объект _damage в функции attack. 
Что-то на подобии :

```
function modify(properties,funct){
    //а что писать здесь никак не пойму
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это наверняка на самый лучший вариант, но он делает, то что тебе нужно (даже немного проще) и без глобальных переменных. Изменить "внутренности" функции можно путем передачи новых параметров. Повникай:

```
var getVariableFunction = (function() {
    var oldA, oldB;
    return function(A, B) {
        oldA = A;
        oldB = B;
        return function(x = oldA, y = oldB) {
            if (x !== oldA && y !== oldB) {
                oldA = x;
                oldB = y;
            }
            console.log(oldA, oldB);
        }
    };
})();


var attack = getVariableFunction(1, 2);

attack(); // 1, 2
attack(); // 1, 2
attack(4, 5); // меняем внутренности // 4, 5
attack(); // 4, 5
attack(); // 4, 5
```

Функцию `modify` сам, думаю, допишешь на основе примера выше (если есть необходимость). Чую заминусуюсь за такой код))

Comment: Спасибо, добавив еще пару аргументов, можно получить то, что я хочу, и оно будет работать. Но разве это можно делать так "function(x = oldA,  y = oldB)"?

Comment: Да, es15 вроде. [Вот тут описано.](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)